# Fresh Install Ubuntu 18.04. USB Storage Devices are not recognized

Tags: 18.04, usb-drive

Recently installed 18.04 on a fresh hard drive.
Everything seems to work, including usb keyboard/mouse, but not usb storage devices.  The usb storage devices (I've tried three different ones) all work on other computers running both Windows and Linux.

Here's the output of `lsusb` (the usb storage device is PNY):

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:0116 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-2971/KU-0325 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 154b:fa64 PNY 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And here's the output of `dmesg`:

```
[  339.995508] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  340.104627] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=154b, idProduct=fa64, bcdDevice=10.75
[  340.104632] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  340.104636] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB 3.0 FD
[  340.104639] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: PNY Technologies
[  340.104642] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: IN1311210000000000000001
[  340.126765] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_sense_invalidCDB (err 0)
[  340.126800] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_adjust_quirks (err 0)
```

And finally, `fdisk` only shows the hard drive:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 446 GiB, 478888853504 bytes, 935329792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x26f11458

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 935327743 935325696  446G 83 Linux
```

**Attempted fixes:**

- I've tried blacklisting the device
- I've tried odd solutions like switching nvidia drivers away from nouveau drivers
- I've tried updating to the latest kernel.
- The issue seems to be isolated to a software/OS issue cause this PNY drive is also a USB live stick which can be booted into.

Still can't connect any usb storage devices.  Please help!

Comment: after installing, did you fully update with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: Ya fully updated. Even made sure the repository list was  complete.

Comment: same issue here. Did you find any fix ? my dmesg report [ 822.982344] usb 3-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd [ 823.003295] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153 [ 823.003301] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1 [ 823.003306] usb 3-4: Product: USB Mass Storage Device [ 823.003309] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: asmedia [ 823.003313] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 123456789012 [ 823.036052] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_sense_invalidCDB (err 0) [ 823.036136] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_adjust_quirks (err 0)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have yet to find a fix.

Answer (score 7):

From RedHat:

**Resolution**

Try loading usb_storage module manually by ignoring install configuration.

**Raw**

```
modprobe --ignore-install usb_storage
modprobe uas
```

**Root Cause**

Check if the usb_storage module is blacklisted.
Module uas has dependency of usb_storage module.
As usb_storage was blacklisted, uas was not able to be loaded, and usb was not detected.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue today on an older RHEL host trying to mount a USB to archive some files.
uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_sense_invalidCDB (err 0)
uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_adjust_quirks (err 0)

I ran these recommended commands.
modprobe --ignore-install usb_storage
modprobe uas

I ran this query again and it reported the error as resolved.
dmesg | grep -i usb

Bonus: The modprobe command also automounted the USB for me under /run/media

Comment: RHEL is off-topic here.